# What’s the difference?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-difference, word-in-context

Is there a difference between “no place to go” and “no place **left** to go”?

e.g.

> There is no place to hide.
>   There is no place left to hide.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference.  What do *you* think the difference might be?  Please add more detail to this question or it might be closed.

Comment: @Andrew it won’t be closed if I delete it first ;) Actually, thank you, this is just what I wanted to know. I can’t provide more info because of my poor English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No place to go**. There ***is*** no place, period. It does not imply there once was a place to go.

**No place left to go**. **There was once a place to go** and now there isn't one.
**There used to be places or a place to go.**

**There's no sugar left**. Meaning: **There was some sugar** and now there isn't any.

I do understand how it might be difficult to explain this if one has limited English so I went ahead and provided the answer.

Comment: Please edit out that bold '**is**' in the first sentence.

Comment: Looks better now

Answer (score 1):

Is there a difference between “no place to go” and “no place left to go”?

Imagine you are stuck in a desert and someone says to you get out from there immediately. So you will say there is no place to go as its a desert.

Imagine you are travelling in some city for almost a month and you got bored and someone tells you to go out and explore the city more. What you will say is there is no place left to go as you are there for a month and each place you must have seen already.

I hope you get the difference.